# Tiled Map in Unity is Darker than in Tiled Editor

Tags: 2d, tiled2unity

I have a problem rendering a Tiled Map in Unity (`.tmx` format): the Tiled Map is darker in Unity than in Tiled Editor.

I tried to change properties but got same result over and over. I will share the pictures, may you take a look and tell what exactly the problem is?

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like a difference of gamma correction. Have you imported your tiles as non-sRGB images and/or did you author them in an app that saves in linear RGB instead of gamma-encoded sRGB? What material/shaders are you using?

Comment: Hi dear @DMGregory I used Tiled Editor, Will add image, exported simply .tmx file. No any over engineering here, I will update my images, so you can see, I didnt use any gamma settings. If you can tell where to check this properties, I will update my question with more images and infos for you.

For Unity, I use simple default material, from path Resources/unity_builtin_extra

Comment: Can you disable the scene lightning? In the first screenshot, the lightning bulb next to the 2d scene icon in the top right in the scene view panel

Comment: Select the texture for one of the tile sprites to show its import settings in the inspector panel

Comment: @Zibelas 0 impact on changing lightning, everything remains same

Comment: I added one more screenshot (Last one), @DMGregory, if I understood wrong, note me and I will change the image

Comment: Try unfolding the asset post-processors, or clicking on the magenta thumbnail beside the asset you've selected.

Comment: I found a solution, thanks to you @DMGregory, the issue was with gamma settings in Player settings !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DMGregory, I found solution !

The solution was changing the Player settings (Color Space -> Gamma)
Important: You need to Reimport Assets and all TMX files

[image]